# Composite pattern in C++ and C# - protected virtual methods

Tags: c#, c++, oop, design-patterns, composite

How can I add a protected virtual method in the "Component" class, so that it can be called from the "Composite"?

As an concrete example, look at the code below, and please tell me how to avoid the compiler error in `DxCompositeShape.ComputeSize`.

```
abstract class DxShape // this is the Component
{
    public abstract void Paint();
    protected abstract void ComputeSize();
}

class DxCompositeShape : DxShape // this is the Composite
{
    public readonly IList<DxShape> Shapes = new List<DxShape>();

    public override void Paint()
    {
        this.ComputeSize();
    }

    protected override void ComputeSize()
    {
        foreach (DxShape sh in Shapes)
        {
            sh.ComputeSize(); // compiler error CS1540
        }
        // and some other logic here
    }
}
```

EDIT: I modified my sample, so I have `ComputeSize` instead of `Init` (people assume that Init can always be called in a constructor).

Comment: So you're giving us C# code, but your question is about both C++ and C#? Why?

Comment: @SebastianRedl If the code is translated in C++, we have the same problem.

Comment: If the code was C++ you could use `friend`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a non-virtual function `Initialise()` in the base class that calls Init

eg:

```
abstract class DxShape
{
    protected void Initialise()
    {
        Init();
    }
    protected abstract void Init();
    //...
}
```

As pointed out in the comments below, `Initialise` must be made either public or static (only in C#), it may remain protected in C++. 
In C++ you could then make Init private and only access it via calls to `Initialise`. See non-virtual interface http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-virtual_interface_pattern

Comment: How about making `Init` a `public abstract` method then? Although, the whole concept of having a method which your derived classes *must call at some point* is wrong.

Comment: +1 for Non Virtual Interface pattern. Its really useful in some cases.

Comment: @Groo Making Init public would let other classes have access to it (defeating the purpose of a non-virtual interface). But you're right, I can't see any benefit of having an Init function over a constructor.

Comment: @Groo I modified my sample, so I have `ComputeSize` instead of `Init`. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: Are you sure that `Initialize` should be `protected` and not `public`? What's the point in doing this, vs. simply making `Init` public?

Comment: Pointing out the obvious, `Initialize` and `Init` are two different functions. In some cases it may make sense to make `Initialize` public if you want to allow other classes to call it. In this case if you did make `Initialize` public, then you may as well just make `Init` public.

Comment: @Lachlan: it may be obvious to you, but I am still not sure how OP's code will work with your modification (the `foreach` loop, specifically).

Comment: Sorry you're right. I read this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9zta243.aspx and made the misconception that the error was due to the function being `protected virtual` as opposed to simply `protected`. This will still work in C++, but may be impossible in C#.

Comment: Now after I read the comments I also tried to compile the code and it's not working :). It is possible to modify it in the following way so it will work: make the Initialise method static with a parameter of type DxShape. So, I think this is a point where C# is not better than C++. Maybe you can add a comment about this in your answer, since I already accepted it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. A protected member of a different object can only be invoked if the compiler can see that the object in question is of the same type as your current object. Basically, "protected" means "Derived classes can use this member in their own class.

The underlying issue here is that you want some privileged classes ("composites") to be able to call a method of foreign classes ("components") that the base class declares is only for use of derived classes in their own implementation.

You might want to make `Init` internal, if all composites are in the same package. Or maybe make a subclass of the component that all composites inherit, and make this particular class privileged to call `Init` on all components. In C++ you would do such a thing with friend declarations. In C#, careful use of internal access is probably the right solution.